# Fill itemsource with data in the combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two combobox, the first is active and the second will be activated only when the first is selected an item. It is depend on the first, what is going to selected, it will build different itemssource for the second combobox with code behind. For example

**Scenario 1**

> I select the first combobox with content 1 and the second combobox
>   will fill itemsource with data A,B,C,D

**Scenario 2**

> I select the first combobox with content 2 and the second combobox
>   will fill itemsource with data T,Z,E,D

My XAML code snippet

```
<UserControl x:Class="RestoreComputer.Views.ConfigView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="50">
            <ComboBox Name="_server" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Servers}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Server}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="18"/>
            <Image Source="../Images/narrow.png" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
            <ComboBox Name="_computer" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Computer}" Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="18">
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=_server}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
            </ComboBox>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the viewmodel

```
public string Server
{
    get { return _server; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _server)
        {
            _server = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ref _server, value, () => Server);
            Computers = GetComputers();
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetComputers()
{
    string nas = ReadServerPath(Server);
    NetworkPath.MapNetworkDrive(nas, SettingsXml.User, SettingsXml.Password);
    var subFolders = new DirectoryInfo(nas);
    IEnumerable<string> folders = subFolders.GetDirectories().Select(e => e.Name).ToList();
    NetworkPath.DisconnectNetworkDrive();
    return folders;
}

public IEnumerable<string> Computers
{
    get { return _computers; }

    set
    {
        _computers = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(ref _computers, value, () => Computers);
    }
}
```

How can I get the desire as mentioned above?

**Updated code:**
XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="RestoreComputer.Views.ConfigView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,0,0" Height="50">
            <ComboBox Name="_server" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Servers}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Server}" Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="18"/>
            <Image Source="../Images/narrow.png" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
            <ComboBox Name="_computer" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Computer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Computers}" Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="18">
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=_server}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
            </ComboBox>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public string Server
{
    get { return _server; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _server)
        {
            _server = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ref _server, value, () => Server);
            if (Computers == null)
            {
                Computers = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            }
            else
            {
                Computers.Clear();
            }

            Computers = GetComputers();
        }
    }
}


public ObservableCollection<string> GetComputers()
{
    string nas = ReadServerPath(Server);
    NetworkPath.MapNetworkDrive(nas, SettingsXml.User, SettingsXml.Password);
    var subFolders = new DirectoryInfo(nas);
    var folders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    subFolders.GetDirectories().Select(e => e.Name).LookUp(folders.Add);
    NetworkPath.DisconnectNetworkDrive();
    return folders;
}
```

And still does not work.

**Update 3**

I changed my code to.

```
public string Server
    {
        get { return _server; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _server)
            {
                _server = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(ref _server, value, () => Server);
                if (Computers == null)
                {
                    Computers = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                }
                else
                {
                    Computers.Clear();
                }

                foreach (var ele in GetComputers())
                {
                    Computers.Add(ele);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetComputers()
    {
        string nas = ReadServerPath(Server);
        NetworkPath.MapNetworkDrive(nas, SettingsXml.User, SettingsXml.Password);
        var subFolders = new DirectoryInfo(nas);
        NetworkPath.DisconnectNetworkDrive();
        foreach (var folder in subFolders.GetDirectories())
        {
            yield return folder.Name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is if you make the binding for Combobox 1 as you did.

And when an Item in combo1 is selected you fill the Computers Collection with the right items. So everytime combo1 SelectedItem changes, the datasource of combo2 changes. And if Combo has no item selected than combo2 has an empty datasource.

Does that help ?

```
public string Server
{
  get { return _server; }
  set
  {
      if (value != _server)
      {
          _server = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged(ref _server, value, () => Server);
          if(Computers == null) {
            Computers = new ObservableCollection<string>();
          } else {
            Computers.Clear();
          }
          Computers.AddRange(GetComputers());
      }
  }
}
```

And you should use ObservableCollection in your ViewModel for all binded lists.

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you use ObservableCollection than the View gets notified if the collection changes. That is what you need here.

**Working Example**

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedList1}"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding List2}"></ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    DataContext = this;
    List1 = new ObservableCollection<string> {"option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"};
    List2 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    InitializeComponent();

  }

  private string m_selectedList1;
  public string SelectedList1
  {
    get { return m_selectedList1; }
    set
    {
      m_selectedList1 = value;
      if (m_selectedList1 == "option1")
      {
        List2.Clear();
        List2.Add("12345");
        List2.Add("123456");
      }
      if (m_selectedList1 == "option2")
      {
        List2.Clear();
        List2.Add("123");
        List2.Add("1234");
      }
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<string> List1 { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<string> List2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I still do not get any items on combox2. I inserted on combobox 2 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Computers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" and computers as ObservableCollection. Combobox 2 is still empty. What do I wrong?

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding Computers}"` try without the explicit trigger

Comment: i create an working simple example for you ... see my updated answer

Comment: I use MVVM pattern. I do nothing in the partial class. I change my code like you told me and still not working.

Comment: it doesnt matter ... my code just has to be in the DataContext. You are doing something different i think :)

Comment: use `Computers.AddRange(GetComputers());`

Comment: I've got compiler error: Error 6 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you are right .... so call GetComputers and fill Computers inside that method ... but `Add()`each item please, else the View is not notified

Comment: why ? is Computers get filled ?

Comment: try adding `Computers = new ObservableCollection<string>();`in ViewModel constructor

Comment: Now it is working. Thanks you so much for help. I put Computers = new ObservableCollection<string>(); in the constructor.. Why I have to initialize ObservableCollection in constructor?

Comment: if you dont the binding Fails for some reason. i dont know the exact reason for this behavior